# Custom class won’t show visuals

Tags: c#, class, label, panel

I’m a novice to C# and OOP, trying to create a math fact battleship board game, and using a custom class to create the board spaces.  My idea was to create an object and put into it a panel, and then in that panel put:

- a label for the math fact
- an int answer
- picture files to show hit, miss, or sunk

Then to load these pieces into a 2D array.  However, when I add the pieces to the board (panel) in the form, I can’t see them.  So I created a simpler test, just a custom class adding a label to a form.  No luck.  I added some code to dynamically create a label that tells me if "this" has any children or not.  It says true, unless I comment out the Add line.  I’d really appreciate it if someone could point out what I’m doing wrong, or at least give me a link to where it is explained online.  I’ve searched and searched.  I’m working in Visual Studio Express 2013.  Intellisense says everything is OK.  Thanks

```
namespace testing_custom_class
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 myLabel = new Class1();
            this.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            myLabel.Show();
            Label childrenTest = new Label();
            childrenTest.Text = this.HasChildren.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(childrenTest);
        }
    }
}

//and from the class1.cs
...
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testing_custom_class
{
    class Class1 : System.Windows.Forms.Control
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're just missing a `this.Refresh()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It didn't help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!  I needed to add the label to "this" inside of the custom class.  I also changed

```
class Class1 : System.Windows.Forms.Control
```

to

```
class Class1 : System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

Then I added the following line:

```
this.Controls.Add(label1);
```

at the end of the custom Class1.  Thanks everybody!

Comment: I don't think switching the Control to Label actually made a difference.  I just wasn't adding the child to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Class1` code, you are inheriting from `Control`. Inherit from `Panel` if you want to extend the functionality of `Panel`.

Also, these two should be declared with class level scope, not inside a function.

```
Class1 myLabel = new Class1();
Label childrenTest = new Label();
```

Comment: I just tried that, thanks, but now even my childrenTest label doesn't work.

Comment: Make the change to Class1 that I suggested. Then delete everything else. Build. Goto the ToolBox and find Class1. Drag it onto the form and VS will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanksf for your help, and your patience.  When I dragged it onto the form, nothing happened in the code, that I could see, so I double clicked on the element.  It added this method:         private void class11_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
Is that right?  A paint method?  If so, how do I use it?

Comment: StackOverflow.com is a GREAT place to get answers to question but what you need to do is to start with tutorials. The MSDN is where you are going to find the best and most accurate information about programming in C#. I would recommend you start here for what you are trying to do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5h0k2e6x(v=vs.80).aspx